# Issue with summing ageing in customized customer statement report

Tags: acumatica

The requirement is to print the customer statement without credit memo and pre payment. I have modified the report and added a filter condition to filter only invoices and it works fine.

I am facing an issue in the ageing where the total is not tallying and it included the credit memo and prepayment.

I have tried to recalculate the values and it is not working.

How do I recalculate the ageing which considers the newly added filter condition?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The have followed the below steps

1. Declared variable for each ageing group in detail band and the value will be reset on document group.
   [image]
2. Declared a variable AgeingDays and calculated the date difference between statement date and document due date

   =DateDiff( 'd',  [ARStatementDetailInfo.DueDate],[@StatementDate] )
3. Used the following statement to find out the ageing group and stored the value

   =$cagb00+Iif($AgeingDays < [ARStatement.AgeDays00], IIf([ARStatement.StatementType]=[@TypeOpenItem],[ARStatementDetailInfo.DocBalanceSigned],[ARStatementDetailInfo.OrigDocAmtSigned]),0)

   =$cagb01+Iif($AgeingDays >= [ARStatement.AgeDays00] And $AgeingDays <[ARStatement.AgeDays01] , IIf([ARStatement.StatementType]=[@TypeOpenItem],[ARStatementDetailInfo.DocBalanceSigned],[ARStatementDetailInfo.OrigDocAmtSigned]),0)

   =$cagb02+Iif($AgeingDays >= [ARStatement.AgeBalance02] And $AgeingDays < [ARStatement.AgeBalance03], IIf([ARStatement.StatementType]=[@TypeOpenItem],[ARStatementDetailInfo.DocBalanceSigned],[ARStatementDetailInfo.OrigDocAmtSigned]) , 0 )

   =$cagb03+Iif($AgeingDays >[ARStatement.AgeBalance03] And $AgeingDays < [ARStatement.AgeBalance04], IIf([ARStatement.StatementType]=[@TypeOpenItem],[ARStatementDetailInfo.DocBalanceSigned],[ARStatementDetailInfo.OrigDocAmtSigned]),0)

   =$cagb04+Iif( $AgeingDays >= [ARStatement.AgeDays04], IIf([ARStatement.StatementType]=[@TypeOpenItem],[ARStatementDetailInfo.DocBalanceSigned],[ARStatementDetailInfo.OrigDocAmtSigned]),0)
4. Declared another set of variable on to sum the value of group level
   [image]
5. Finally while printing ageing value, check the flag invoice only and if it is true print the calculated value otherwise the default value

=Iif([@InvoiceOnly], $ca01, $CustAgeBalance01 )

I have tested and my test result are good.

Comment: We tested this change against customer's data and found that aging works for few customers but not for all, there is some issue with this report calculation where the aging gets messed up so not a fully working report yet, appreciate if anybody has any input on this ...

Answer (score 0):

I tangled with this report once and it was a tough exercise.  My requirements were different,but in the end I had to tinker with how the variables within the report are calculated based on the data. In the report designer, click on the sections and then click into the variables collections under properties.  You can see how the balances are summed and edit the code, put in if statements,etc. Hope that's helpful.